# Como criar um site dinâmico como os blogs normais na web

Tags: php, blog

Preciso de ajuda em uma dúvida que venho tendo.
A URL dos blogs em geral na web são por diretórios por exemplo:
www.qualquercoisa/post/exemplo-do-post.

Estou criando um blog que é dinâmico e utilizo parâmetros na URL para exibir o conteúdo na pagina, exemplo:
www.qualquercoisa/post?id=1.

O banco de dados tem uma tabela chamada `post`, exemplo:

```
nome varchar     | conteúdo: <h1>Meu primeiro post</h1>
conteudo varchar | conteúdo: <p>Este é o meu conteudo do primeiro post</p>
```

Quando o usuário clica no link, vai para um arquivo chamado `post` e junto com ele o ID do post para exibir. Com o ID consigo pegar no banco de dados o nome e o conteúdo.

Dúvida: É errado fazer desta forma? Os blogs normais tem de criar um arquivo com o post quando quiserem postar uma matéria? Criar um arquivo para cada post não pesaria no servidor?

Comment: Pesaria. A técnica que é utilizada e você deve pesquisar é reescrita de URL. Você define um *entry-point* padrão para toda a sua aplicação e trata a URL acessada. Normalmente é definida uma relação 1:1 entre a URL e o post (no geral, através do título do post após o processo de *slugify*)

Comment: Obrigado, vou pesquisar sobre.

Comment: Só uma dúvida: você está fazendo isto "na unha" de propósito? Pois poderia facilmente fazer tudo em Wordpress.

Comment: @RogérioDec o site é sobre programação. Se fosse pra usar wordpress, nem faria sentido ele perguntar aqui, afinal no WP já tem o recurso pronto. Mas de curiosidade, pra que alguém usaria WP hoje em dia com tanta coisa melhor (feita na mão, inclusive).

Comment: @RogérioDec Estou fazendo na unha para entender como tudo funciona. Antes de usar qualquer framework quero entender o que acontece por trás das cortinas.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Bacco, há muitos anos eu desenvolvia sites em Drupal, pois na época o Wordpress era basicamente um criador de blogs. Mas atualmente WP está muito bem avançado. Mas quais CMS você diz serem bem melhores que Wordpress?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tenho que te agradecer novamente. O que você falou era o que eu precisava. Não resolvi totalmente meu problema, mas encontrei um caminho. vlw man